# MySQL table with 2000 million records how to optimize

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, bigdata

For a website having 2000000 users, out of which each user shares thousands of pictures and on each picture there will be thousands of comments, in such scenario there will be more than 2000 million comments, so how can I manage this much of big data using MySql. How can following methods improve performance of my database server

1. Use of table partationing
2. Use MySQL clusters
3. Use MySQL with memcached

Please explain other methods and best practices to handle such big database tables

Comment: I'd say your projections are a bit high... By your math every user of the site will have written on average a million comments. If you really have a web site of that magnitude, you'll probably need to hire a team of SQL experts who manage the database.

Comment: 2000000 users * avg. 5000 photos per user * avg. 2000 comments per photo = 2e+13

Comment: Do you really think there will be 2000 comments on *every* photo? It would actually mean that every user will write on avarage 5000*2000 = *10,000,000* comments in total. Even if it's projected over 10 years, it would mean that every one of the 20m users writes a comment every 30 seconds nonstop day and night.

Comment: Assuming that each comment is only 40 chars long you will need roughly 727TB of disk space to store the comments. You will be spending a fortune in disks alone. I think @Juhana is correct in saying your projections are a bit high. I have worked for some rather large organisations where 10 years worth of production data is not that big.

Comment: @Juhana you are getting it wrong, on a photo sharing website it is common for a user to have 5000 images in his account and on each image we can at least consider thousand comment by his/her friends.. my question is not how much comments will be there..ok you can decrease one or two zero form the 2000000 records :) but still it is a big data..so what planning will I have to do to manage this much big data.

Comment: You are confusing average with high-water-mark. If a couple of users have 5000 images, it doesn't mean that the *average* is 5000. You should look at what's the *most common* situation. I'm guessing here, but I'd say in practically all photo sharing websites about 90% of photos have from zero to one comments, maybe 0.1% have more than 100 comments and 0.01% or less have more than a thousand. The same goes for users: most will not upload a single photo.

Comment: ok, please check this new figures of comments 2000000 * ((5000*90/100)*1 + (5000*0.1/100)*100 + (5000*0.01/100)*1000 + (9.89*10/100)*10) = 11019780000 comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of the mentioned optimization, choosing the right indexes on the right fields is crucial for your query performance, make sure your tables are indexed on everything you group, order or search based on.

Also make sure to check out Chapter 8 of the MySql reference which discusses [optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization.html)
What you really should be focusing on is optimizing the [structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-database-structure.html), [queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-optimization.html) and [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html) before getting into memcached and MySql clusters.

As your database grows you monitor the performance and optimize accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i dont thinl traditional RDBMS is what you need :) , more like NoSQl is what would serve you best

Comment: Based on what evidence? This is very generalized statement.

Comment: fact is the data that is out of a site like how you describe can benefit more from a non rdbms because most of these kind of data is not heirarchial. Since most of the effort is put into normalizing and indexing, getting those data out is going to be expensive in the long run.

Comment: So without seeing the actual data structures you came to this conclusion. I should hire you then. Seriously a suggestion without analysis of what is the real situation is dangerous.

Comment: have you seen the solution? yes you should fire yourself first